# Kafka producer doesn't send messages after Spring-Cloud and Spring boot upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

After upgrading Spring Boot to version 3.0.6 and Spring Cloud to 2022.0.4 and java 17, springBootVersion=3.0.6,springDocVersion=1.67,
springCloudVersion=2022.0.4,springCloudFunctionVersion=3.2.9 the Kafka producer doesn't work. When testing on a lower version, it works. Please find code properties detai,dependecies details and code below

Here is stream cloud stream properties

## Spring Cloud Stream Binding Properties

```
     spring.cloud.function.definition=filterWaClientData
     # filterWaClientData Binding (Consumer)
     spring.cloud.stream.bindings.filterWaClientData-in-0.destination=tax-payroll- 
      datafeed-evt-load-clt-dnr
     spring.cloud.stream.bindings.filterWaClientData-in-0.consumer.use-native- 
     decoding=true
     spring.cloud.stream.bindings.filterWaClientData-in-0.group=wa-client-stream
     spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.filterWaClientData-in-0.consumer.start- 
      offset=latest
     
     # filterWaClientData Binding (Producer)
     spring.cloud.stream.bindings.filterWaClientData-out-0.destination=tax-payroll-wa- 
     evt-client-clt-dnr
     spring.cloud.stream.bindings.filterWaClientData-out-0.producer.use-native- 
      encoding=true
     
     # Kafka Binder Properties
     # spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers is set by EmbeddedKafka
     
     # Let EmbeddedKafka create topics
     spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.auto-create-topics=false
     
     # Kafka Consumer Properties
     spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer- 
      properties.schema.registry.url=mock://mock-schema-registry
     spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.specific.avro.reader=true
     spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer- 
     properties.key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.
     ByteArrayDeserializer
     spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer- 
     properties.value.deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
     
     # Kafka Producer Properties
     spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer- 
     properties.schema.registry.url=mock://mock-schema-registry
     spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer- 
     properties.key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
     spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer- 
     properties.value.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
     
     # Kafka Security/Connection Properties
     spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.security.protocol=PLAINTEXT
     
    spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.ssl.endpoint.identification.
    algorithm=
     
     # ----------------------------------------
     # TRACEABILITY PROPERTIES
     # ----------------------------------------
     info.app.component=test
```

Here is my dependecies

```
        dependencyManagement {
        imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud- 
        dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function- 
        dependencies:${springCloudFunctionVersion}"
        }
        }

        dependencies {
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2"
        implementation "org.jolokia:jolokia-core:1.6.1"
    
        implementation"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka"
    
        // Kafka dependencies
        implementation "io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:6.1.11"
        implementation "org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.1"
        implementation("com.entsvcs:payx-entsvcs-kafka:1.0.31-SNAPSHOT") {
            transitive = false
        }
        implementation("com.entsvcs:payx-entsvcs-common-v2:2.0.75-SNAPSHOT") {
            transitive = false
        }
    
        // Kafka traceability
        implementation 'com.traceability:traceability-cloud-stream-autoconfigure:3.1.+'
    
        // Health Monitoring
        implementation("com.cloud.sidecar:health-monitoring-mbean:1.2.0.master.+")
    
        testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
            exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
        }
    
        testImplementation 'com.obsidiandynamics.pojotester:pojotester:0.9.0'
        testImplementation "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test"
        testImplementation("org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.8")
    }
```

```java
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
                @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE, properties = 
               "spring.jmx.enabled=false", classes = Application.class)
                @TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
                @ImportAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
                        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
                        TransactionAutoConfiguration.class,
                        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
                @EmbeddedKafka(controlledShutdown = true,
                            bootstrapServersProperty = 
                           "spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers",
                            topics = {SubscriptionServiceTests.INPUT_TOPIC_NAME,
                                    SubscriptionServiceTests.OUTPUT_TOPIC_NAME}, 
                            partitions = 1)
                  public class SubscriptionServiceTests {
                
                static final String INPUT_TOPIC_NAME = "tax-payroll-datafeed-evt-load-clt- 
                dnr";
                static final String OUTPUT_TOPIC_NAME = "tax-payroll-wa-evt-client-clt-dnr";
                
                    @Autowired
                    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;
                    
                
                    private KafkaTemplate<byte[], PayrollClientData> kafkaTemplate;
                    private Consumer<byte[], ClientJurisdictionData> consumer;
                
                    @BeforeEach
                    void init() {
                        kafkaTemplate = 
                KafkaTestFactory.getKafkaTemplate(embeddedKafkaBroker.getBrokersAsString());
                        consumer = 
                 KafkaTestFactory.getConsumer(embeddedKafkaBroker.getBrokersAsString(), 
                 "test-group-id");
                    }
                
                    @Test
                    public void filterWaClientDataTest() {
                        // Subscribe to output topic before publishing events
                        embeddedKafkaBroker.consumeFromAnEmbeddedTopic(consumer, 
                     OUTPUT_TOPIC_NAME);
                        
                        PayrollClientData payrollCltData = PayrollClientData.newBuilder()
                            .setFileId("125")
                            .setLoadId("231")
                            .setRunId("9001")
                            .setBranchNumber("0017")
                            .setQuarter("4")
                            .setYear("2020")
                            .build();
                
                        // Publish event
                        kafkaTemplate.send(INPUT_TOPIC_NAME, payrollCltData);
                
                        // Consume single event
                        ConsumerRecord<byte[], ClientJurisdictionData> consumerRecord = 
                        KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(consumer, 
                        OUTPUT_TOPIC_NAME);
                        ClientJurisdictionData receivedValue = consumerRecord.value();

Error:

   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No records found for topic
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(KafkaTestUtils.java:181)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(KafkaTestUtils.java:142)
```